# What's the difference between `Where did you think I was all this time?` and `Where did you think I have been all this time?`?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I have recently heard the first sentence `Where did you think I was all this time?` in a movie but my intuition as a non native speaker tells me that present perfect would suit better this case because "...I was all this time..." sounds like a indefinite time with connection to the present...

So my choice if I were to say something like this would be something like

`Where did you think I have been all this time?`

Is the second option wrong or Do they convey different meanings?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your sample sentence's verb tenses clash.  *Where **did** you think I **had been** all **that** time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a slightly different meaning, but not of much practical importance.

> Where did you think I was all this time?  - All this time, where were you imagining that I was?
>
> Where **do** you think I have been all this time? - Where (now) do you think I was?

Your version *Where did you think I have been...?* is not obviously wrong, but seems to me slightly illogical.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on EllieK's comment, the version **Where did you think I have been** sounds wrong for a very simple reason:

Where **did** you think: past tense
I **have** been: present (perfect) tense

If the person was thinking in the past, they can't have been thinking about the current present!